# How to appose WrapPanel items of different heights (vertically)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, tiles

This is how it looks like right now:

[image: Tiles, not apposed]

and this is how I'd like to have it:

[image: Tiles, apposed]

As shown the tiles should be apposed as densely as possible with only a set margin between them.

And here's my code:

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <TextBox x:Name="BoardNameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="40,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="pol" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Grid Margin="0,30,0,0" Background="WhiteSmoke">

        <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <WrapPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#4DB4DD" />
                </Style>
            </WrapPanel.Resources>

            <Rectangle Width="150" />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle Width="200"/>
            <Rectangle Height="25"/>
            <Rectangle Height="40"/>
            <Rectangle />
            <Rectangle Width="220"/>
            <Rectangle Height="30"/>
            <Rectangle Height="30"/>
            <Rectangle Width="150" />
            <Rectangle />
        </WrapPanel>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The code is of course a sample code for my particular problem - later on it should just be a wrap panel (or any other control) with the items (which are custom controls) added programmatically (like "WrapPanel1.Children.Add(r);"). I hope the images are self-explanatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called cascading layout.it has a very popular implementation in javascript called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which has a `WPF` counterpart known as  [WPF-Masonry](https://github.com/Lizzaran/WPF-Masonry) .check preceding links for detail and demo.