# Place blocks with different heights like tiles with a specific order - WPF, XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I just started to use WPF. I cannot find the answer for my question on google for some reason...
I want to place blocks with different heights to implement the cascading layout. I saw this answer [How to appose WrapPanel items of different heights (vertically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158561/how-to-appose-wrappanel-items-of-different-heights-vertically), but it uses the 3-rd part implementation.
My code:

```
    <WrapPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <WrapPanel>
                <GroupBox Header="Block1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="50" Background="Gray"/>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Block2">
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="150" Background="LightBlue"/>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="Block3">
                    <StackPanel Width="200" Height="25" Background="LightCoral"/>
                </GroupBox>
            </WrapPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
```

When the window is at normal state, it looks ok:

[image: Window, normal state]

But when the window was maximized, it looks so:

[image: Window, maximized state, wrong look]

It should look like that:

[image: Window, maximized state, right look]

Where to search? What to search? What can I do to implement this behavior?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure that there is anything in WPF out of the box that would give you the desired result. If you really really want the feature, then you could look at the git hub repo of the solution posted in the question you linked.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to check out something like [VariableSizedWrapGrid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/995465/VariableSizedWrapGrid-for-WPF) or [Masonry](https://github.com/Lizzaran/WPF-Masonry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if they're all the same width (and just the height is different) just have the `WrapPanel` lay them out vertically. At least it'll get rid of the horizontal gap:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <GroupBox Header="Block1">
        <StackPanel Width="200" Height="50" Background="Gray"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Block2">
        <StackPanel Width="200" Height="150" Background="LightBlue"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Block3">
        <StackPanel Width="200" Height="25" Background="LightCoral"/>
    </GroupBox>
</WrapPanel>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]